# Java interview test

Tags: java, testing, tdd

This morning in a work interview they asked me if I get a some legacy code with no tests at all, and I need to modify something, how would I do it to be completely sure that I break nothing.

My answer was, first of all I would create a test for the part of the code I need to modify, then once the test is passing, I would do the modification of the code ensuring that the test is still passing. So basically doing it from a test driven development approach.
I did not see the the person interviewing me really ok with myanswer so, I would like to have your opinions on the subjects, there are better approaches for that?

Is it valid my answer?

Thank you very much

Comment: It is, I would answer same way :)

Comment: If you want to be *absolutely* sure you don't break anything, don't change it. Otherwise there'll always be a risk that you break something elsewhere in the system. You can minimise the risk with appropriate testing, but you can never get rid of it completely.

Comment: If after that you felt that they were looking for more I would then have suggested that a number of new tests be added that **fail** with the current code but would **pass** if the fixes were correct. I would then request a code review of the tests before making any changes to the code.

Comment: pretty much write tests cases to test all the functions of the old code, and then making changes in the meantime monitoring if the test cases still pass. You answered really well IMO

Comment: Another technique to change legacy code with some confidence that you aren't breaking existing functionality is [golden master](http://blog.thecodewhisperer.com/2014/09/28/surviving-legacy-code-with-golden-master-and-sampling/).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Your answer is correct, but maybe too simplified.**

In the real world, it is usually not that easy. Especially for legacy systems where a lot of code is too much coupled, there are bad abstractions, inefficient language constructs, etc. It is especially challenging if there are no other tests and that happens.

Also sometimes it is just not that easy to mock out the dependencies if they are hardcoded. Then it depends on the mocking framework capabilities if it allows mocking out final classes, static methods, etc.

Maybe good thing to mention is few patterns from the the "Working Effectively with Legacy Code" book.